# Use different colors in same graphics (Java)

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java.

I need to do an exercise which draws different random shapes, with different positions and colors. I want every shape to have a different color. This is a part of my code (which has two different shapes, an oval and a rectangle). Now the two shapes have the same random color:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  Color color = new Color(R, G, B); // picks a random color
  int ovalA = (int)(Math.random()*400);
  int ovalB = (int)(Math.random()*300);
  int ovalC = (int)(Math.random()*(400 - ovalA));
  int ovalD = (int)(Math.random()*(300 - ovalB));
  int rectA = (int)(Math.random()*300);
  int rectB = (int)(Math.random()*400);
  int rectC = (int)(Math.random()*(400 - rectA));
  int rectD = (int)(Math.random()*(300 - rectB));
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(color);
  g.fillOval(ovalA, ovalB, ovalC, ovalD);
  g.fillRect(rectA, rectB, rectC, rectD);
```

}

Comment: So why don't you just create another random color? Also, you should probably initialize the random colors outside the paintComponent() method, that way it doesn't change every time you repaint the component.

Comment: you are using the same color for all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  Color color = new Color(R, G, B); // picks a random color
  g.setColor(color);

  int ovalA = (int)(Math.random()*400);
  int ovalB = (int)(Math.random()*300);
  int ovalC = (int)(Math.random()*(400 - ovalA));
  int ovalD = (int)(Math.random()*(300 - ovalB));
  g.fillOval(ovalA, ovalB, ovalC, ovalD);


  R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  B = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  color = new Color(R, G, B); // picks a random color

  int rectA = (int)(Math.random()*300);
  int rectB = (int)(Math.random()*400);
  int rectC = (int)(Math.random()*(400 - rectA));
  int rectD = (int)(Math.random()*(300 - rectB));
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(color);
  g.fillRect(rectA, rectB, rectC, rectD);
}
```

Now, here's the explanantion behind it, when you had the code the way you did it, you did not get a new random set of numbers for your color, the ints that you used stayed the same even when you did ask for the color. I just used math.random to change those values again before making a color out of them

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Thanks everyone for your answers and suggestions.

Comment: @GastonM008 If this solved your problem, you should try resizing the window ;-)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are using the **same** `Color` objects for both shapes. You have to create a new `Color` object for each shape that should be drawn in a new color.

I'd recommend to set up a utility method for this. This method could roughly look like the following:

```
private static final Random random = new Random(0);
private static Color createRandomColor() {
    int r = random.nextInt(256);
    int g = random.nextInt(256);
    int b = random.nextInt(256);
    Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
    return color;
}
```

This way, you can easily draw shapes with different random colors:

```
g.setColor(createRandomColor());
g.fillOval(ovalA, ovalB, ovalC, ovalD);
g.setColor(createRandomColor());
g.fillRect(rectA, rectB, rectC, rectD);
```

---

An aside: I generally recommend to use `java.util.Random` instead of `Math.random`. The main reasons for that are that `java.util.Random` offers some utility methods, like the `nextInt` method that is used in the above method and comes in really handy here. Additionally, the `Random` instance can be created with a certain *seed*, and will then always return the same sequence of random numbers, which can make debugging *much* easier (in fact, in some cases, only this can make debugging even *possible*!). If you want "real" random numbers again, you can simply create the `Random` instance *without* a seed.

---

EDIT: Kevin Workman made an important point in his comment:

> Also, you should probably initialize the random colors outside the paintComponent() method, that way it doesn't change every time you repaint the component.

But since you are also creating the *shapes* randomly during each call to `paintComponent`, everything will flicker and blink when you resize the window anyhow.

Usually, the `paintComponent` method should ***only*** paint. No data should be read or created there. For your application case, you could solve this by creating a `List` containing `Shape` objects, along with a list containing `Color` objects. I'll add an example here in a minute.

EDIT2: Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomShapePainter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().add(new RandomShapePanel());

        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class RandomShapePanel extends JPanel
{
    private final List<Shape> shapes;
    private final List<Color> colors;

    private static final Random random = new Random(0);

    RandomShapePanel()
    {
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            shapes.add(createRandomShape());
            colors.add(createRandomColor());
        }
    }

    private static Shape createRandomShape()
    {
        boolean b = random.nextBoolean();
        if (b)
        {
            return createRandomOval();
        }
        return createRandomRectangle();
    }

    private static Shape createRandomOval()
    {
        // Hard-coded constants should be avoided,
        // just for illustration here
        double x = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double y = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double w = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double h = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
    }

    private static Shape createRandomRectangle()
    {
        // Hard-coded constants should be avoided,
        // just for illustration here
        double x = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double y = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double w = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        double h = 100+random.nextInt(300);
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
    }

    private static Color createRandomColor() 
    {
        int r = random.nextInt(256);
        int g = random.nextInt(256);
        int b = random.nextInt(256);
        Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
        return color;
    }    


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        for (int i=0; i<shapes.size(); i++)
        {
            Shape shape = shapes.get(i);
            Color color = colors.get(i);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fill(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your answer, `createRandomColor` doesn't have a return value.